# Iterate rows in dataframe df_a and update dataframe df_b based on df_a values in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe **df_b** which has to be updated based on dataframe **df_a** values

**df_a**

```
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
| id_1| id_2| header_oper| head_seq|
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
|  boy|    3|      insert|        1|
|  bat|    4|      delete|        3|
|  cat|    2|      insert|        1|
|  bat|    4|      update|        2|
|  bat|    5|   beforeimg|        1|
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
```

**df_b** (before)

```
+-----+-----+
| id_1| id_2|
+-----+-----+
|  boy|    4|
|  bat|    5|
|  cat|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

**The method I came up with:**

1. Sort df_a on 'head_seq'.
2. Iterate df_a
3. if 'header_oper'.isin('insert','update') then append that row to df_b
4. if 'header_oper'.isin('delete','beforeimg') then subtract that row from df_b

Expected **df_b** (after):

```
+-----+-----+
| id_1| id_2|
+-----+-----+
|  boy|    4|
|  boy|    3|
|  cat|    2|
|  cat|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

Need help on how to iterate df_a and perform operations on df_b based on df_a values.

Comment: Can you elaborate the requirement? Few things are unclear  : `cat|2|insert|1|` is inserted in `df_b` but `bat|4|update|`  is not..

Comment: bat|4|update| is processed but then also deleted; bat|4|delete|. Hope that clarifies

Answer (score 0):

```
ds= spark.createDataFrame([('boy',4),('bat',5),('cat',1)],['id_1','id_2'])
df_op=spark.createDataFrame([('boy',3,'insert',1),('bat',4,'delete',3),('cat',2,'insert',1),('bat',4,'update',2),('bat',5,'beforeimg',1)], ['id_1','id_2','eff_op','seq'])

effective_op=df_op.groupBy('id_1').agg(max('seq').alias('seq')).join(df_op,['id_1','seq'])

ds_insert=ds.union(effective_op.select('id_1','id_2').filter("eff_op in ('insert')").orderBy(asc('id_1')))

ds_delete=ds_insert.join(effective_op.filter("eff_op in ('delete')").select("*"),['id_1'],'left').select(ds_insert.id_1, ds_insert.id_2).filter("eff_op is null")

display(ds_delete)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. As there's beforeimg for every update, the order of the operations didn't matter.

I just had to add all the Inserts and Updates and then delete the Deletes and BeforeImgs

**Partitioning the operations and deselecting the header columns**

```
ins=df_a.where(df_a['header_oper']=='insert')
ins=ins.select(id_1,id_2)

upd=df_a.where(df_a['header_oper']=='update')
upd=upd.select(id_1,id_2)

dele=df_a.where(df_a['header_oper']=='delete')
dele=dele.select(id_1,id_2)

bimg=df_a.where(df_a['header_oper']=='delete')
bimg=bimg.select(id_1,id_2)
```

**Appending the Inserts and Updates to df_b**

```
df_b=df_b.union(ins)
df_b=df_b.union(upd)
```

**Removing the Deletes and BeforeImgs from df_b**

```
df_b=df_b.subtract(dele)
df_b=df_b.subtract(bimg)
```